# How to mend these 2 Main Scripts Inside of ServerScriptService, as 1 Main Script Working Individually

Tags: lua, roblox

First Script:

```
local rep = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage") local mapsfolder = 
game:GetService("Lighting"):WaitForChild("Maps")
local rep = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local mapsfolder = game:GetService("Lighting"):WaitForChild("Maps")

local booleans = rep:WaitForChild("Booleans")
local variables = rep:WaitForChild("Variables")
local choice1 = variables:FindFirstChild("Choice1")
local choice2 = variables:FindFirstChild("Choice2")
local choice3 = variables:FindFirstChild("Choice3")
local winner = variables:FindFirstChild("Winner")
local timer = 60 --in seconds




while true do
while true do
    
    
local maps = mapsfolder:GetChildren()
choice1.Value = maps[math.random(1,#maps)]
table.remove(maps,table.find(maps,choice1.Value))
choice2.Value = maps[math.random(1,#maps)]
table.remove(maps,table.find(maps,choice2.Value))
choice3.Value = maps[math.random(1,#maps)]
table.remove(maps,table.find(maps,choice3.Value))
wait(5)
booleans:FindFirstChild("VotingSession").Value = true
wait(50)
booleans:FindFirstChild("RevealVotes").Value = true
wait(5)
booleans:FindFirstChild("VotingSession").Value = false
booleans:FindFirstChild("RevealVotes").Value = false
local chosenmap = winner.Value

if not winner.Value then
    print("Something went wrong!")
    break
    end
    
    --
local map = chosenmap.Value
local clonemap = map:Clone()

print("Getting map...")
wait()
print("Getting map spawn...")
if clonemap.Spawn then
    print("Success!")
else
    print("Task failed successfully")
    wait()
    print("Restarting...")
    clonemap:Destroy()
    break
end
clonemap.Parent = workspace
    print("Getting players...")
    wait(1)
local players = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()
for x, player in pairs(players) do
    local char = player.Character
    if not char then
        print(player.Name.." has no character!")
    else
        local humanoidrootpart = char.HumanoidRootPart
        if not humanoidrootpart then
            print(player.Name.." has no HumanoidRootPart!")
        else
            humanoidrootpart.CFrame = clonemap.Spawn.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3,0)
        end
        end 
    wait()
end
for i = timer,0,-1 do
    print(i)
    wait(1)
end
for x, player in pairs(players) do
    local char = player.Character
    if not char then
        print(player.Name.." has no character!")
    else
        local humanoidrootpart = char.HumanoidRootPart
        if not humanoidrootpart then
            print(player.Name.." has no HumanoidRootPart!")
        else
            humanoidrootpart.CFrame = workspace.Lobby.SpawnLocation.CFrame + 
 Vector3.new(0,3,0)
        end
    end
    wait()
end
clonemap:Destroy()
end
end
```

second script:

```
waitTeam = "Cyan" -- The team for the waiting room.

waitTime = 60 -- The time spent in the waiting room before battle.

battleTeam = "Bright red" -- The team for the battle arena.

battleTime = 60 -- The amount of time the battle will last.

winBonus = 1 --The KO bonus given to the last man standing.

tieBonus = 1 --If more than 1 player is left standing, then this will be added to the standing 
player's KOs.

local Status =  game.ReplicatedStorage.Status


battle = false

function onDiedInBattle(humanoid, player)
local stats = player:findFirstChild("leaderstats")
if stats ~= nil and battle==true then
    local deaths = stats:findFirstChild("Wipeouts")
    deaths.Value = deaths.Value + 1

    player.TeamColor = BrickColor.new(waitTeam)
    print("Player died")



    local killer = getKillerOfHumanoidIfStillInGame(humanoid)

    handleKillCount(humanoid, player)
    local playersStillInBattle = {}
    for i,child in pairs(game.Players:getChildren()) do
        if child.TeamColor == BrickColor.new(battleTeam) then
            table.insert(playersStillInBattle, child)
        end
    end
    if #playersStillInBattle <= 1 then
        battle = false
        Status.Value = "All players have been eliminated!"
        task.wait()
        nameWinner()
        changePlayersToTeamColor(waitTeam)
        killAllPlayers()
    end
    end
end

function getKillerOfHumanoidIfStillInGame(humanoid)

local tag = humanoid:findFirstChild("creator")


if tag ~= nil then

    local killer = tag.Value
    if killer.Parent ~= nil then 
        return killer
    end
end

return nil
end

function handleKillCount(humanoid, player)
local killer = getKillerOfHumanoidIfStillInGame(humanoid)
if killer ~= nil then
    local stats = killer:findFirstChild("leaderstats")
    if stats ~= nil then
        local kills = stats:findFirstChild("Wins")
        if killer ~= player then
            kills.Value = kills.Value + 1

        else
            kills.Value = kills.Value - 1

        end
    end
    end
end
```

---

```
function onPlayerEntered(newPlayer)
wait()

local kills = Instance.new("IntValue")
kills.Name
    = "KOs"
kills.Value = 0

local deaths = Instance.new("IntValue")
deaths.Name
    = "Wipeouts"
deaths.Value = 0


while true do
    if newPlayer.Character ~= nil then break end
    wait()
end

newPlayer.Changed:connect(
    function(property) 
        if property == "Character" and newPlayer.TeamColor ~= BrickColor.new(battleTeam) then
            print("Player spawned, removing tools")
            for i,tool in pairs(newPlayer.Backpack:getChildren()) do
                if tool.className == "Tool" or tool.className == "HopperBin" then
                    tool:remove()
                end
            end
        end
    end
)

if newPlayer:findFirstChild("leaderstats") == nil then
    local stats = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stats.Name
        = "leaderstats"
    kills.Parent = stats
    deaths.Parent = stats
    stats.Parent = newPlayer
else
    kills.Parent = newPlayer.leaderstats
    deaths.Parent = newPlayer.leaderstats
end

newPlayer.TeamColor = BrickColor.new(waitTeam)

for i,tool in pairs(newPlayer.Backpack:getChildren()) do
    if tool.className == "Tool" or tool.className == "HopperBin" then
        tool:remove()
    end
end
end

game.Players.ChildAdded:connect(onPlayerEntered)

function status(text, time)
local msg = Status.Value..("Message")
msg.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage.Status
msg.Text = text
wait(time)
msg:remove()
end

function changePlayersToTeamColor(color)
for i, player in pairs(game.Players:getChildren()) do
    if player.Neutral == true then
        player.Neutral = false
    end
    player.TeamColor = BrickColor.new(color)
end
end

function killAllPlayers()
for i, player in pairs(game.Players:getChildren()) do
    player.Character.Humanoid.Health
        = 0
end
end

function beginBattle()
for i, player in pairs(game.Players:getChildren()) do
    if player.Character.Humanoid.Health
        <= 100 then
        while true do
            if player.Character ~= nil then
                if player.Character.Humanoid.Health
                    >= 0 then break end
            end
            wait()
        end
    end
    print(player.Name.." is now ready for battle.")
    player.Character.Humanoid.Died:connect(function() 
 onDiedInBattle(player.Character.Humanoid, player) end)
 end
end

function nameWinner()
local winners = {}
function getWinners()
    for i,player in pairs(game.Players:getChildren()) do
        if player.TeamColor == BrickColor.new(battleTeam) then
            table.insert(winners, player)
        end
    end
end
getWinners()
if #winners == 1 then
    winners[1].leaderstats.KOs.Value = winners[1].leaderstats.KOs.Value + winBonus
elseif #winners > 1 then
    for i=1, #winners do
        winners[i].leaderstats.KOs.Value = winners[i].leaderstats.KOs.Value + tieBonus
    end
end
if #winners == 1 then
    Status.Value = "The winner of this game was "..winners[1].Name.."."
    task.wait(1)
elseif #winners == 0 then
    Status.Value = "Everyone died in this game."
    task.wait(1)
elseif #winners == 2 then
    Status.Value = "The game was tied between "..winners[1].Name.." and 
"..winners[2].Name.."."
    task.wait(1)
elseif #winners > 2 then
    string = "This game was tied between "
    for i=1, #winners - 1 do
        string = string..winners[i].Name..", "
    end
    string = string.."and "..winners[#winners].Name.."."
    status(string, 3)
end
end

while true do

status("Game will begin in "..waitTime.." seconds!" , 6)
wait(waitTime)

changePlayersToTeamColor(battleTeam)
killAllPlayers()
print("Let the battle begin!", 3)
Status.Value = "The battle will last "..(battleTime/60).." minutes!"
task.wait()
battle = true
beginBattle()
local btime = 0
while battle == true do
    btime = btime + 1
    if btime >= battleTime or not battle then break end
    wait()
end
print(btime)
if battle == true then
    battle = false
    Status.Value = "The battle is now over."
    task.wait(1)
    nameWinner()
    changePlayersToTeamColor(waitTeam)
    killAllPlayers()
else
    wait()
end
wait()
end
```

---

What I need Essentially: Is the First Main Script to Run the Voting sessions, Then once it spawns the character in-game to the cloned map, The Second Script Runs and Does Its part as the game mode script which essentially causes the game to end as One Person is left. Please, If you can Help I have been attempting to do this for 2 days..This is my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing call spawn(functionName) which is like creating a new script that will run independently on a new thread. Which means the main script can keep doing it's own thing while the Spawned function does its own thing on a different thread.

In your case, you could create a function named startRound(), that will control the round. And spawn the function after teleporting players to the map. Also, don't forget to put all the code inside the first script.

```lua
function startRound(){
    while true do
        status("Game will begin in "..waitTime.." seconds!" , 6)
        wait(waitTime)

        changePlayersToTeamColor(battleTeam)
        killAllPlayers()
        print("Let the battle begin!", 3)
        Status.Value = "The battle will last "..(battleTime/60).." minutes!"
        task.wait()
        battle = true
        beginBattle()
        local btime = 0
        while battle == true do
            btime = btime + 1
            if btime >= battleTime or not battle then break end
            wait()
        end
        print(btime)
        if battle == true then
            battle = false
            Status.Value = "The battle is now over."
            task.wait(1)
            nameWinner()
            changePlayersToTeamColor(waitTeam)
            killAllPlayers()
        else
            wait()
        end
        wait()
    end
end
```

Notice: I've removed some of the code just to make the code shorter. You don't need to remove the code, instead you have to add the spawn(startRound) part.

```lua
while true do
    while true do   
        print("Getting players...")
        wait(1)
        local players = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()
        for x, player in pairs(players) do
            local char = player.Character
            if not char then
                print(player.Name.." has no character!")
            else
                local humanoidrootpart = char.HumanoidRootPart
                if not humanoidrootpart then
                    print(player.Name.." has no HumanoidRootPart!")
                else
                    humanoidrootpart.CFrame = clonemap.Spawn.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,3,0)
                end
            end 
            wait()
        end
        --[[ Begin the Round inside a spawn ]]--
        spawn(startRound);

        for i = timer,0,-1 do
            print(i)
            wait(1)
        end
    end
end
```